# Best way to handle a five star rating system?

Tags: database-design, web-development-server

I'm working on app I'm developing to put on my portfolio.  It's a pretty simple app where users can review products based on a five star rating system.  I'm pretty new to web development/database design and definitely in the learning process so I'm not sure of the best way to handle this.

Currently I have a table of users, a table of products, and a table called "feedback" that stores the votes, any comments left, and foreign keys linking to both users and products.  When a user searches for a product it performs a query that selects the products from the products table, and joins each product to their related votes which are grouped by average.

Everything works totally fine as it is, but I'm curious if it would be better to keep the feedback table, but add a column in the products table that stores the average vote, which updates every time the feedback table is updated.  My thought was, hypothetically, if this app had thousands of users and tens of thousands of votes then querying the feedback table for every product every time someone performed a search might end up being slow; whereas if I store the average in the product table then the feedback table only needs to be queried on a new/updated vote (or if someone wants to see the individual comments left for a product).  On the flip side, storing the average vote in the feedback table seems like it could be considered redundant (I know I'd be storing very little additional data so it might be inconsequential, but I still want to learn how to do things the right way!)

Which would be better for performance?  Or am I completely overthinking this?

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb is that you shouldn't store anything that could be computed easily from your already stored data, especially not on a different table - as then you would need to have a sync mechanism (usually in the form of triggers) that is going to slow down data manipulation (though admittedly not significantly) and will be another part of your database to maintain. (not to mention another operation for the database to log on every data change, and the potential for data inconsistencies.

Given proper indexing, computing the average vote of a specific product from the feedback table should be quite a fast operation, even with considerable amounts of data.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!  I actually did end up using some triggers to store the data in the product table before I read your answer; I figured as I'm new to all this it could be a good learning experience.